# okhttp3 is throwing java.net.ConnectException when calling .intercept()

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Here the code I am using

```
class VerificationInterceptor(private val helper: RequestHelper) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response =
        chain.proceed(chain.request()).apply {
            if (code == 200
                && !chain.request().url.toString().contains(BuildConfig.root)
                && !chain.request().url.toString().contains(LOCAL_HOST_BASE)
            ) {
                if (!helper.getResponseCryptoVerification(
                        headers,
                        peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE).string()
                    )
                ) {
                    throw IOException("Error while generating Hmac for Response JSON")
                }
            }
        }

}
```

This line here `chain.proceed(chain.request()).apply {` is crashing with this stack trace

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect()(PlainSocketImpl.java:-2)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect()(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress()(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect()(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect()(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
    at java.net.Socket.connect()(Socket.java:605)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket()(AndroidPlatform.kt:58)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket()(RealConnection.kt:268)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect()(RealConnection.kt:176)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection()(ExchangeFinder.kt:236)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection()(ExchangeFinder.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find()(ExchangeFinder.kt:77)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange$okhttp()(Transmitter.kt:162)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept()(ConnectInterceptor.kt:35)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed()(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed()(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept()(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed()(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed()(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept()(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
```

**The question is what is causing the crash? How to catch it and proceed with the request chain?**

Comment: The failure may be unrelated to your interceptor.

Comment: the crash starts chain.proceed(chain.request()) and the log points to the proceed() and then socket connect() sequence it kinda pointed me to think it is directly related. Do you have any other idea what can cause ConnectException if not the proceed call

Comment: @Rainmaker any chance you've resolved?  I'm having the exact same trace with a custom interceptor

Comment: @AndrewG no unfortunately even submitting the bug to Retrofit and okhttp client didn't help. I just wrapped it into try catch and in catch create an error body to fail gracefully.